# Lie Groups of bigger cardinality

Tags: lie-groups

A Lie Group is  to be a group that is also a manifold, and of course a manifold is a second countable Hausdorff space. Now the maximum cardinality for a second countable (Hausdorff)space is $\beth_{2}$ = $\mathcal P^{2} \left({\mathbb{N}}\right)$. Now most of the classical Lie groups have the cardinality $\beth_{1}$(the cardinality of the continuum). Are there any examples of Lie groups with the largest possible cardinality? If there please expound on them.

Comment: They're second countable, but also locally Euclidean. So manifolds are countable unions of copies of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Excellent point, Tim! For any topological space X such that Card(X)= $\beth_{2}$, any mapping $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow X$ is not a bijection; and thus cannot be a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

A second countable $T_1$ space has cardinality at most $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$. For let $\tau_X$ be its topology; we may write any open set as a union of elements of the countable basis. Picking such a decomposition for each open set gives us an injection $\tau_X \hookrightarrow \mathcal P(\Bbb N)$. Because our space is $T_1$, points are closed, and hence we also have an injection $X \hookrightarrow \tau_X$ (given by $x \mapsto X \setminus \{x\}$). So not only is the cardinality of $X$ at most that of $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$, the cardinality of the topology is, too. Of course, Hausdorff space, hence manifolds, are $T_1$. (As a result of this and the locally Euclidean property, positive dimensional manifolds have cardinality $\big|\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\big|$.)